# jQuery tab plugins - benefits over selfmade?

Tags: plugins, tabs

i wonder if there is any benefit of using a  tab plugin. I mean its not that hard to show and hide stuff (divs, text) with jQuery.

I'm interested what the pros say :-)

Regards from Germany - so sorry for typing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It handles any browser compatibility issues
2. Can be themed
3. Plays well with other jQuery components